# Variable JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json, date

Traigo los campos de una tabla vía JSON, se imprimen perfectamente como `<td>{{data.Vence}}</td>`. Mi problema es que quiero comparar esta fecha con hoy + 30 para ver si es menor y declarar una alarma, pero no he podido hacerlo ya que no puedo accesar esta fecha `{{data.Vence}}`.

```
<?php
    $t = strtotime('+30 days');
    $f = '{{data.Vence}}';
    echo $f; (ESTO FUNCIONA BIEN, hasta aquí)
    /*if (strtotime($f) < strtotime($t)) {
        echo "Rojo";
    }else {
        echo "Verde";
    }
    */
?>
```

Comment: has intentado decodificar el json con json_decode en php?

Comment: Entiendo lo que buscas, lo que no entiendo es que ya dices que tienes la fecha en formato json, porque no la puedes comparar mediante javascript?

Comment: Coloca Por favor el Codigo para poder ayudarme mas claramente a tu problema

Comment: Si entiendo, pero no el array no está conmigo, está en otra página. Entonces no puedo usar decode, era más fácil tomar la variable y convertirla, lo cual no me resulta

Comment: La comparo pero falla, tengo que convertir primero y no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

en php (si $f y $t estan en formato en -> aaaa-mm-dd), puede comparar fechas con el objeto Datetime. (hay otras formas ademas de esta)

```
$of = new \Datetime($f);
$ot = new \Datetime($t);

if ($ot < $of) ...
```